# Vue - Get id of particular clicked post

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, increment

Basically my goal is **getting the number of click for each post**.

Until now, i only just successfully get the number per clicks on console :

[image]

But i need to know which post was clicked, For distinct that, **i want to display the id of post**, so i supposed each post have some: `_id`

That is my post content from my DB :

[image]

My code :

```
<template>
 <div w="3" v-for="(post, post_id) in posts" :key="post_id">
   <div class="card-view" @click="getStat(post_id)">
    <div class="container">
     <a href="#"><div class="tag_name blue">{{ post.title }}</div></a>
     <div class="company">{{ post.body }}</div>
     <div class="c_logo">
       <img :src="`${post.image}`"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
 name: "Home",
 components: {
   modal,
 },

data: () => ({
  posts: [],
}),

methods : {
  getStat : function() {
    let increment = this.counter += 1
    console.log(increment)

    let result = axios.post("http://localhost:3000/allPostClicked", {
        numberOfClick: increment,
        postID: this.post_id
    })
    console.log(result)
    }
  },
},
</script>
```

...and when i clicked on some post, i got this error on my console :

```
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12) at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:54:7)
config
: 
{url: 'http://localhost:3000/allPostClicked', method: 'post', data: '{"numberOfClick":null}', headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
isAxiosError
: 
true
request
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly take a look at following snippet

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    posts: [],
  }),
  async mounted() {
    await this.getPosts()
      this.posts = this.posts.map(p => {
        return {...p, numberOfClick: 0}
    })
  },
  methods : {
    async getPosts() {
      await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.posts = json)
    },
    getStat(id) {
      const post = this.posts.find(c => c.id === id)
      post.numberOfClick++
    },
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div w="3" v-for="(post, i) in posts" :key="i">
    <div class="card-view" @click="getStat(post.id)">
      <div class="container">
        <h5 class="tag_name blue">{{ post.title }}</h5>
        <div class="company">{{ post.body }}</div>
        <h3>{{ post.numberOfClick }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @nicola-pavicevic thanks for your reply,  i try you code but the value of ```numberOfClick```doesn't change, i think is the ```_id``` maybe ??

Comment: @Thestrike95 hey mate, of course, this is just a demo, you need to set your fields names you receive from back-end

Comment: @nicola-pavicevic Yep it just worked !, i successfully change ```ìd``` to ```_id```, Thank you so much !